# Reliability of HTML5 Localstorage for storing offline data in mobile application

Tags: html, sencha-touch-2, local-storage

I am developing a mobile application using Sencha Touch. My app needs to store some data (which comes from a database, in JSON format) in the device itself, so that the app retains its previous state if it's closed and rerun.

Is HTML 5 localstorage the best possible solution?

What are its limitations/shortcomings?

If I delete the browser cookies, will I also lose the locally saved data?

What alternative do I have other than to save in web browser's cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalStorage is a viable solution, along with IndexedDB.  LocalStorage is supported in more browsers, but only supports storage of strings in Name/Value pairs. Here are the support tables:

- [LocalStorage Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)
- [IndexedDB Support](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb)

Another option would be SequelSphere, an HTML5 Relational Database Engine that uses LocalStorage and IndexedDB to store its data.  It also has an Extension for Ext JS 4 (Sencha's big brother), and a Sencha Extension in the works.  Even without an extension, it can store your data locally, provide SQL access, and put the data in a form for easy use by Sencha.  As a disclaimer:  I work for SequelSphere.  That's how I know a Sencha extension is in the works.

When it comes to reliability, all forms of client side data storage are reliant upon the end user not clearing the data from their browser.  Please note:  this is usually a different option than clearing the browser's cookies.